# Delete vector data and not to push forward

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector which has data of

> Record 1: 03: Ted
>   Record 2: 06: Mary
>   Record 3: 23: Ferry

How do I delete `Record 2`, in a way that `Record 3` data wont push up and eventually it becomes `Record 2`?

Comment: Show us the code please.

Comment: So you'd need a filler element? Why not a map?

Comment: @Andy Prowl - I didn't know std:vector didn't push element 3 to 2 if 2 is deleted?

Comment: @user93353: I might have misunderstood the question

Comment: @user1745860 What would you expect to be at the second place after you have deleted it?

Comment: @user1745860: do you want the elements after the deleted one **not** to be moved, or to be moved?

Comment: You would either have to save the ID of the record in the record data structure itself or use a type that supports non-consecutive indices like `std::map`.

Comment: It looks like you are imbuing important data-driven semantics to the numeric key. But in vectors and arrays the numeric key has no meaning other than for ordering. Use a different container.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, use a map of record numbers to records:

```
std::unordered_map<std::size_t, Record> records{ //or std::map in C++03
    {1, {"03", "Ted"}}, //or records[1] = Record("03", "Ted") in C++03
    {2, {"06", "Mary"}}, //or records[2] = Record("06", "Mary") in C++03
    {3, {"23", "Ferry"}} //or records[3] = Record("23", "Ferry") in C++03
};

records.erase(2); //leaves records[1] and records[3] intact
```

For a complete demonstration, [see here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/36BbdL%242) fpr C++11, or [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/36BbdL%247) for C++03, though the C++03 one could be improved with `insert` so there's no default constructor for `Record` needed. I suppose the C++11 one could use `const` when iterating as well, though that's beside the point.

Comment: In C++11 I would prefer `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: Or, maybe not If you want to iterate over the in the right order.

Comment: @ipc, True, but record 3 is still record 3. Unless the question adds more specific info, an unordered map is better. It just happens that the example orders 1 and 3 reversed, so that should stand out.